# Compare whether a float value is within a particular range in java/android

Tags: java, android

I have a float value in my code.

I wish to use multiple if else statements to check whether it is within the range (0,0.5) or (0.5,1) or (1.0,1.5) or (1.5,2.0). Please suggest a way for me to achieve this.

Earlier I thought, I can get the exact value of float. So, I was using the below mentioned code. But then I realised that it is not wise to use == clause for float variables. So, now I need to check whether the variable value is within a particular range.

```
float ratings=appCur.getFloat(appCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID));


            if(ratings==0){
                ivRate.setImageResource(R.drawable.star0);
            }
            else if(ratings==0.5){
                ivRate.setImageResource(R.drawable.star0_haf);
            }
            else if(ratings==1){
                ivRate.setImageResource(R.drawable.star1);
            }
            else if(ratings==1.5){
                ivRate.setImageResource(R.drawable.star1_haf);
            }
            else if(ratings==2){
                ivRate.setImageResource(R.drawable.star2);
            }
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    float x = ...
    if (x >= 0.0F && x < 0.5F) {
        // between 0.0 (inclusive) and 0.5 (exclusive)
    } else if (x >= 0.5F && x < 1.0F) {
        // between 0.5 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive)
    } else if (x >= 1.0F && x < 1.5F) {
        // between 1.0 (inclusive) and 1.5 (exclusive)
    } else if (x >= 1.5F && x <= 2.0F) {
        // between 1.5 (inclusive) and 2.0 (inclusive)
    } else {
        // out of range
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In this way?

```
  float n;
```

...

```
  if (n<0.5f)  {  // first condition
  } else if (n<1f) { // second condition
  } else if (n<1.5f) { // and so on...
  }
```